# List of forms on a webpage

Tags: html, blazor

I want to display a list of contact addresses.
Each contact has information such as name, street, city, country, phone, email, website, ...
There are several hundred addresses I have to display.

A contact has to be editable on demand. That is if the user clicks an "edit" button on the side.
Now here is my issue: Is it appropriate to have several hundred forms on page which I activate with the click on the button?
Or is it better to display the data in a `<div>`, `<p>` layout and have something like a modal with the form popup?

Does it cause problems to have so many forms?

Comment: I think a modal popup would be better for the User, especially on a Phone.

Answer (score 1):

Having so many forms will cause the webpage to become bulky and slow, and it will be a hassle to maintain. In order to avoid having hundreds of forms on one page, you can have a single form which is dynamically edited according to which contact address the user selects.

Comment: Those forms would come from a loop, maintenance = 1x.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem. MDN approves of multiple forms in one page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Comment: Where do you see "Approve" ? They use it in a demo, not exactly the same.

Comment: @HenkHolterman If it's an example on MDN, it is semantically correct. Therefore, it is generally approved to use multiple forms in one page.